# how to make an enemy shoot in the players direction

Tags: java

I'm making a tankgame. I already found out how to make my enemy move in the direction of the player, but I'm not quite sure how to make it shoot in the players direction. Also the shooter of the tank has to rotate towards the direction of the direction the enemy is shooting. (the bullet has to 'come out' of the shooter)

[image: shooter] this has to rotate, I already wrote the code to make the shooter of the player follow the position of the mouse

I put the shooter on the body of the tank [image: body]

as bullets we use black circles: (`ObjWH` is `ObjectWidhtHeight`)

```
`public void draw(Graphics2D g)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillOval((int) (x_pos - objWH), (int) (y_pos - objWH), (int)  objWH, 
        (int) objWH);
    }`
```

i want to store the bullets from the enemies in ArrayLists, every enemy needs its own ArrayList.

```
`package tanks;

import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.Timer;

import menu.PlayPanel;
import menu.Tanks;

    public class Enemy extends Game_Object {

        private static final Timer shootTimer = null;
        private PlayPanel panel;

        int launchPosition;

        double distance;
        double deltaX, deltaY;

        private ArrayList<EnemyBullet> enemyBullets;

        public Enemy(PlayPanel panel)
        {
            this.panel = panel;
            speed = 3 + rand.nextInt(5); 
            maxHP = 80 + rand.nextInt(40); 
            HP = maxHP;
            angle = 0; 
            angleCannon = 0;
            objWH = 65;

        }

    public void launch() 
    {
        launchPosition = rand.nextInt(3);

            switch(launchPosition){
            case 0: //up
                x_pos = rand.nextInt(Tanks.getSchermBreedte());
                y_pos =  0;
                break;

            case 1: //left
                x_pos = 0;
                y_pos = rand.nextInt(Tanks.getSchermHoogte());
                break;

            case 2: //downside
                x_pos = rand.nextInt(Tanks.getSchermBreedte());
                y_pos = Tanks.getSchermHoogte();
                break;


            case 3: //right
                x_pos = Tanks.getSchermBreedte();
                y_pos = rand.nextInt(Tanks.getSchermHoogte());
                break;  
            }
        }

        public void move()  
        {
            if (Player.get_x_pos() >= Enemy.get_x_pos())
            {
                deltaX =  Player.get_x_pos() - Enemy.get_x_pos();
            }
            else //if(Player.get_x_pos() <= Enemy.get_x_pos())
            {
                deltaX = Enemy.get_x_pos() - Player.get_x_pos();
            }

            if(Player.get_y_pos() >= Enemy.get_y_pos())
            {
                deltaY = Player.get_y_pos() - Enemy.get_y_pos();
            }
            else //if(Player.get_y_pos() <= Enemy.get_y_pos())
            {
                deltaY =  Enemy.get_y_pos() - Player.get_y_pos();
            }

            distance =  Math.pow(Math.pow(deltaX, deltaX) + Math.pow(deltaY,            
                deltaY), 1/2);

            x_move = speed*(deltaX/distance);
            y_move = speed*(deltaY/distance);

            x_pos += x_move;
            y_pos += y_move;
        }


        private static double get_x_pos()  
        {
            return Enemy.x_pos;
        }           

        private static double get_y_pos()
        {
            return Enemy.y_pos;
        }


        public void shoot()
        {

            enemyBullets = new ArrayList<EnemyBullet>();
        }

        public void touched()
        {
            if(HP>0)
                HP -= (5 + rand.nextInt(10));   

            if(HP <= 0)
                dood = true;
        }

        public void draw(Graphics2D g2d)
        {
            body = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/objects/enemy 
                tank.png")).getImage();
            shooter = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/objects/enemy 
                shooter.png")).getImage();
        }
    }`
```

Comment: i also made a class `EnemyBullet `because it actually seemed more logic to me to make everything about the bullets in 1 (seperate) class


the only code i wrote in the class so far is `public void draw(Graphics2D g)`

Comment: Think about to post/move your question [here](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: If I understand, your tank can move in the player's direction, but theirs shooters do not focus him ?

Comment: i haven't written the code for the enemy to shoot yet, and that is basically my question because i don't really now how to make it a) focus and b) shoot

Comment: @Lola For the focus, arctan is all you need (as already said by Mike Robinson). For shooting, basically you have to define a velocity vector in function of the tank orientation (`vx=k*cos(angle)` and `vy=k*sin(angle)`, where `k` represents the bullet's speed and `angle` the orientation of the shooter), and then update the bullet position with it (`bullet.x += vx` and `bullet.y += vy`).

Answer (score 3):

Well, the essence of this will be "basic geometry," specifically the function `ATAN2`.  *(Google it...)*

Imagine that there is a right-triangle with your tank at one vertex, and the enemy at the opposite end of the hypotenuse.  `ATAN2` can tell you the angle of that vector (and in which "quadrant" it lies).  Usually, the calculation is in radians, not degrees.

In order to achieve realistic motion, your tank's logic must regularly calculate this angle and then turn by some increment *towards* it.  If the angle is now sufficiently small, that the bullet will hit the target, the tank fires.

I'm not going to offer you a "code-writing service," but this is the essential math of it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you look up some examples of how to calculate with 2D vectors. I am not quite sure which framework you are working with. Usually game engines or frameworks have vector classes.

A vector looks something like this (x,y). So you have the two coordinates you need. If you subtract the position where your bullet has to start(v1) from the position where it shall go to(v2) you get a direction vector.
The calculation looks like this.

v3.x = v2.x - v1.x
v3.y = v2.y - v1.y

This vector can be multiplied with a speed factor. Then you simply add the position vector of the bullet.

A common method to interpolate between to methodes is lerp(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation) or slerp. These are to algorithms. You can use this for rotation.

Is this helpful or totally useless? I am glad to help you further as long as i can.

Answer (score 0):

The basic logic behind rotation of an object towards a certain direction, essentially making the object look towards that direction can be expressed as follows:

```
private double calculateAngle(double vecX, double vecY) {
    double angle = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(vecY / vecX));
    return vecX > 0 ? angle : 180 + angle;
}
```

where `vecX` and `vecY` are the `x` and `y` values of the vector (direction). This can be obtained by subtracting `x, y` values of your enemy from `x, y` values of the "shooter". Finally just apply rotation transformation with the angle returned from the method to your "shooter" object